# Pure-FTPd Configuration on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, ubuntu-12.04, pureftpd

I have a fresh installation of pure-ftpd on Ubuntu Server 12.04, and for the life of me I can't find any kind of central config file. All I need to do is set a passive port range. At this point I would settle with knowing its default passive port range (assuming it has one) so I can go change the firewall to match it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "10000 11000" > /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/PassivePortRange
```

I found this by reading the manpage for `pure-ftpd-wrapper`:

> ```
>    pure-ftpd-wrapper reads the configuration for the Pure-FTPd daemon
>    from files in the directory /etc/pure-ftpd/conf. Each file in this
>    directory is related to a command line option. 
>    ...
>    Two numbers
>        "AnonymousRatio", "LimitRecursion", "PassivePortRange",
> ```

I was directed to that manpage by `/usr/share/doc/pure-ftpd/README.Debian` (which I found from looking through `dpkg -L pure-ftpd|grep -i doc`:

> ### pure-ftpd for Debian
>
> Please note that these packages use a complete new configuration
>   scheme, read the pure-ftpd-wrapper manual page for more information.

Comment: Thanks! Especially for the documentation finding tip. Too often I know there must be documentation for a problem but I'm clueless as how to find it.Would it hurt to have a note at the top of the pure-ftpd manpage about the new configuration scheme? Or at least a reference to pure-ftpd-wrapper in the SEE ALSO section??

Comment: Yeah, from my brief tour I assumed it was a change from the Debian packagers who may not necessarily be the same as the `pure-ftpd` authors.  If this is the case, it may explain why this seems a little "bolted-on."

Answer (score 0):

Try the next variant:

```
echo "40000 50000" > /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/PassivePortRange
/etc/init.d/pure-ftpd restart
```

Where 40000 is the minimal passive port and 50000 is the maximal passive port for ftp.